# How to add second, lower power source to car fog light?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm trying to make my fog lights work with the parking lights, so I have one continuous strip of light. While I'm handy enough to craft it, designing the circuit so that I retain proper factory functionality is beyond my skills. I'll try my best to explain what I need, please go easy on me if I mess up some terms.

[image]

1. The rear parking lights consist of one 21/5W (leftmost, also brake light) and one 5W bulb (center). The fog light uses а 21W bulb (rightmost, in the trunk partition of the taillight).
2. Since the fog light is driver-side only, I'll add another 21W bulb to the passenger side.
3. I'll run a wire from the driver-side 5W parking light, into the trunk, *through the components that you kindly suggest I use*, and finally to both fog light bulbs.
4. There needs to be a resistor somewhere along the line, and the bulbs need to be wired in paralell, due to the bulb holder design.

The result of this mess - when I switch the parking lights on, the fog lights also light up - using 5W of power each (hence the resistor), so they are exactly as bright as the other two bulbs.

**Here come the tricky parts:**

- I have no clue how to calculate the proper resistor needed to power two 21W bulbs, wired in parallel, at 5W
- Maintaining the fog light functionality - the driver side bulb should be able to draw full power from the factory wire when needed
- I would like current to only go one way - no current should go from the fog light to the parking light, or from the parking light to the headlight switch module
- The original fog light circuit needs to be the default - the CANBUS system checks the bulb at startup and I refuse to live with a "bulb out" warning

I would like to use simple components - relays, diodes and so on.

**A million thanks!**

Comment: "so they are exactly as bright as the other two bulbs." - May not work. A 21W bulb may or may not (probably not) be as bright or of similar color as a 5W bulb at 5W each.

Comment: @jsotola Not sure we're talking about the same thing here, because it may vary by language and jurisdiction. But there are countries where "fog lights" in the front are plain white lights which may legally only be turned on in rain/fog. And there are also red fog taillights brighter than regular back lights and fitted on one or both sides also only for use in rain/fog.

Comment: What is the legal limit for the brightness of the parking lights in your country? You might need to change the existing ones for 2.5 W bulbs if you are doubling the number of bulbs.

Comment: @AndrewMorton He may not be (street) legally modifying the lights on his vehicle *at all* because it may void his car's type approval.

Comment: "I refuse to live with a "bulb out" warning" - This complicates things somewhat. I'd rule out powering 3x5W from a lamp that's designed for 1x5W, so just connecting more lamps is not an option. A relay and an extra power supply may be required. What kind of car is it? Do you know if it uses switched +12V or switched ground to control the lights?

Comment: I'm not a car expert or a lawyer, but as an engineer, I can say: 1) fog lights are mounted at the front of a car, in order to see through fog when you drive, you will never find them behind the car, which has the potential to blind people who follow you in the traffic 2) The equation for a current-limiting resistor to a diode is V=IR, it depends on the diodes characteristic and how much power it consumes. You have to consult your LED's datasheet to compute the current. Also for high power, a simple resistor might get too hot, so you might need more complex current limiters.

Comment: @darksky 1) Then what do you call the bright, red extra lights in the back you may turn on in fog? 2) We're not talking LED but incandescent here.

Comment: Got them: [Rear fog lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_lighting#Rear_fog_lamps)

Comment: @JimmyB I'm afraid I have never heard of such thing. There are only two types of tail light bulbs I'm aware of: the type that you turn on at night, usually red, and the type that turns on when you set the transmission to reverse, they are usually white.

Comment: @JimmyB that's interesting. Are you living in the constant fog climate? I'm curious why you are so worried that cars behind you notice you in the fog? How does your suggested mod have potential to improve you car or your driving as opposed to annoy someone behind you?

Comment: @darksky I *think* the OP is concerned less about safety than about aesthetics ;-)

Comment: Here in Europe there are two types of fog lights: White or yellow at the front and red at the back. The red rear one is obligatory. The front ones are optional but there are rules about angle and brightness. I can't for the world see how any authority would allow two white rear fog lights! They  would panic any driver if they appear in front of them and would (not could!) cause fatal swerving!

Comment: What @oldfart said. There are reasons for the lighting regulations on cars. Safety is the major main one. And uniformity across manufacturers/models

Comment: Regarding safety and added brightness - modern cars with all-LED lights already have much higher brighteness.

Regarding safety - around here more than half of the cars' headlights are poorly aimed, blinding oncomming traffic. I don't see how 10 addidional watts is going to be a problem.

Comment: The mod is purely aesthetic, however it is not destructive - factory fog light will still function as intended.

Comment: Does the parking light come on on a different side depending on the position of the indicator switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQoWqT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A basic circuit which ought to work would be as above.  The diodes should be rated at least 2A - the 1N5400 is 3A.  The tricky bit is going to be the resistors.  If you put 5W through a 21W lamp, it will glow feebly.  You would need some trial-and-error to find what actually works.  The resistors need to be high power wire-wound ones.

Comment: Simon, thank you for taking the time! I have two questions though. 1) Why are there two 5W bulbs? If that is meant to be the passenger side bulb, that one has its own wiring - the driver and the passenger side are completely separate. 2) Could I use a single resistor for both 21W bulbs? Basically remove R1 and have the wire going to D1 branch off after R2?

Comment: Oh, and a third question - if I understand correctly, diodes still let just a tiny bit of current the opposite way. Should I be worried about this, or is it negligable?

Comment: @J.Doe I was thinking of the left and right bulbs.  You can forget about the second one.  I will try updating the diagram.

Comment: @J.Doe I did the two 21W lamps with separate resistors to avoid doubling the load on the fog light circuit.  If that circuit can handle two fog lamps, then that would be simpler.

Comment: I did this yesterday and it worked like a charm. The store only had 1N5402 diodes and up, and I got a 25W 10 ohm adjustable resistor, so all components exceed specs, giving me peace of mind. The resistor I fixed at around 65%, so I guess 6-7 ohms results in the correct brightness.

Thanks, Simon!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to draw what I think you want to do.

This is the starting point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwcoLf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And this is about what you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feOmry.png)</sup>

Add one diode between each R and its lamp and you can use a SPST relay instead which may be acquired more easily/cheaply.

As Simon B said, the resistor values for matching brightness need to be figured out by experiment; maybe start at 50 Ohm and reduce in steps of 5-10 Ohm until you're satisfied. As to their power rating, they should be on the order of the lamps, i.e. 20W should be pretty safe. Note that the resistors may get hot while running, so allow for some space and means to transfer the heat away.

Also, the bulb out check might get confused because of the extra current the relay draws from the parking light. It may not detect the 'overcurrent' but may fail to detect a broken bulb because some current still flows through the relay.

Comment: JimmyB, thank you for the answer! I chose to go with Simon's solution for two reasons: 1) There was the possibility that the canbus check energises the coil for a brief moment at engine startup, making the bulbs flash briefly. 2) I was going to be constantly concerned about the relay taking a beating from me just closing the trunk.